# Hadoop custom writable

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to write more than one value in the output of the job. To do that I am using a custom writable that implements the interface `Writable`. This custom writable, I called it, `CompositeWritable` implements the two methods for reading and writing. When I run the job, the output looks like this:

```
key CompositeWritable@5fdf281b
lean    CompositeWritable@2153b010
likely  CompositeWritable@2153b010
```

What am I missing? In the job specification, I set the output value class to be `CompositeWritable`. ANy other settings I have missed?

Comment: When you say "output" are you looking at the output file? What OutputFormat are you using? This appears to be the output of the inherited "toString" from java.lang.Object.

Comment: yes, the output file. Not specifying the output format, I guess it is TextOutputFormat.

Comment: Tried explicitely setting `job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class)` but the same result.

Comment: Post your Writable code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TextOutputFormat seems to rely on the toString method from the writable ([see line 80](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/TextOutputFormat.java#TextOutputFormat.LineRecordWriter.writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29)). Implement a reasonable override of toString on your CompositeWritable class,for example you could call to string on the contained items and append them together with a separator.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return ___________;
    }
```

Example:

```
@Override
        public String toString() {
            return key+","+value;
        }
```

Here key and value is seperated using "," seperator.You can use any seperator as your wish.